# Spring boot app not starting due to Service Class Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a spring boot application to insert data into H2 DB. But the application is not starting itself. I am getting some bean error. I am newbie in creating spring application not able to solve this error.

I have created Model Class as shown below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPENDENCY_ANYWHERE")
public class DepedencyAnywhere implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PACKAGE")
    private Long packageId;

    @Column(name = "DEPENDENT_PACKAGE")
    private Long depedencyPackageId;

    public DepedencyAnywhere() {
    }

    /**
     * @return the packageId
     */
    public Long getPackageId() {
        return packageId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the depedencyPackageId
     */
    public Long getDepedencyPackageId() {
        return depedencyPackageId;
    }

}
```

Dao Class as shown below

```
@Repository
public class DependencyAnywhereDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    public void add(DepedencyAnywhere depedentPackages) {
        em.persist(depedentPackages);

    }

    public DepedencyAnywhere getDepedendentPackage(Long packageId) {
        return em.find(DepedencyAnywhere.class, packageId);
    }

}
```

I created Service Class shown below

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DependencyAnywhereService {

    @Autowired
    private DependencyAnywhereDao dependencyAnywhereDao;

    public void add(DepedencyAnywhere depedentPackage) {
        dependencyAnywhereDao.add(depedentPackage); 
    }

}
```

This is my controller class

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class APIRestController {

    @Autowired
    DependencyAnywhereService dependencyAnywhereService;

    @RequestMapping("/insert")
    public String insert() {
        DepedencyAnywhere dependencyAnywhere = new DepedencyAnywhere();
        dependencyAnywhereService.add(dependencyAnywhere);
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

This application is not getting started and I'm getting error like

> Field dependencyAnywhereService in com.hpe.oss.installer.controller.APIRestController required a bean of type 'com.hpe.oss.installer.service.DependencyAnywhereService' that could not be found. Where I am going wrong? Is this some configuration issue?

Comment: can you post your main class, and why did you put "@EnableAutoConfiguration" in APIRestController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EnableAutoConfiguration is scanning packages for spring components which you located under Controller, likely your Controller is not in root package, so context  contain probably just not see components (service and repository). You should locate the annotation in root of you package.

Comment: Problem with the EnableAutoConfiguration scanning. I corrected in my main class.